# values not passing correctly?

Tags: java, variables, methods

I have a simple program I am supposed to write. In three methods I need to read in integers, reverse them, and determine if they are palindromes or not. For some reason the numbers always come back as not palindromes even when they obviously are.

This is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class main
{

public static boolean isPal;
public static void main(String[] args)
throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    int num;
    int ctr = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("data4.txt"));
    num = input.nextInt();

    while(num != -999)
    {            
        ctr++;
        reverse(num);
        isPalindrome(isPal, num);
        if(isPal == true)
        {
            System.out.println (num + " is a palindrome");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(num + " is not a palindrome");
        }
        num = input.nextInt();
    }        
    System.out.println(ctr + " numbers were processed.");
    System.out.println("End of Program");
}

public static int reverse(int num)
{
    int dig;
    int rnum = 0;
    while(num != 0)
    {
        dig = num % 10;
        num = num / 10;
        rnum = rnum * 10 + dig;
    }
    return rnum;        
}

public static boolean isPalindrome(boolean isPal,int num)
{
    if(num == rnum)
    {
        isPal = true;
    }
    else
    {
       isPal = false; 
    }
    return isPal;
}    
}
```

and the inputs are

3579
6336
5115
-999

Comment: `isPalindrome(isPal, num);` Do something with this... it's not C.

Comment: amongst the many problems you are passing a primitive `boolean` into a method and probably expecting its value to be changed outside the method, it won't be, see the dupe I selected for this. then see Ryan's comment and read about `shadow variables` and `variable scope`.

Answer (score 0):

You have two variables named `rnum`, one member of your class, and a different one local in your `reverse()` function. Fix that.

Comment: Well, you removed the member `rnum` and now your code as given doesn't even compile.